# How to reduce space between and across geom_bar in ggplot2 R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I want to: (a) Reduce space between P1 and P2 (I tried position.dodge as suggested by others but no luck there) (b) Reduce space between the organs "A","B" and "C",

```
organ <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C")
val <- c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0)
plant <- c("P1","P2","P2","P1","P1","P2","P2","P1","P1","P2","P2","P1")
order <- c("P1 first","P2 first","P1 first","P2 first","P1 first","P2 first","P1 first","P2 first","P1 first","P2 first","P1 first","P2 first")

df <- data.frame(organ,val,plant,order)

ggplot(aes(x = plant, y= val, color = plant, fill=plant), data = df) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', width = 0.3,position = position_dodge(width = 100)) + 
  facet_grid(order~organ) + theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use `geom_col(width = 1)` and then resize your graph to get a nice-looking result?

Comment: Also, you should position `theme(legend.position = "none")` after `theme_classic()`.